# Evaluating homework question effort

Tags: discussion, homework

Im wondering if anyone would like to suggest a framework by which we should evaluate homework questions.

More specifically the fact that we require effort to be put into a homework question before we allow it on the site.

Such a question is driven by  [densep](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/1601/denesp) comment on the question: [Microeconomics exercise involving utility functions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18282/microeconomics-exercise-involving-utility-functions)

As a newer member of the site and moderator, I'd like to open the floor to more senior members of the site.

Answer (score 7):

I consider [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/15631/61) to be a good example of an admissible homework question. The OP states the problem clearly enough, it presents his solution, then states what's troubling him with the solution he found.

In cases where the OP has trouble reaching the end either for reasons of understanding or lack of technical/mathematical knowledge, I would say that "show your efforts" means

"elaborate as to *why* you cannot proceed further -don't just say 'I'm clueless' or equivalent".

Presenting the problem also is an important part of "show effort" -don't just throw a "what XXXX means" question to our forum.